# $1/4$ people like wine in a country

Tags: probability

In a country, $1/4$ people like wine, $1/9$ of those who wear glasses like wine and $1/3$ of those who don't wear glasses don't like wine.

We chose randomly one citizen, what's the probability:

$1.$ that he wears glasses and likes wine?

$2.$ that he wears glasses if it's known that he doesn't like wine?

*Attempt*

$1.$ I tried $1/4\times 1/9=1/36$

$2.$ I tried $P(\text{wears glasses}|\text{likes wine})=\frac{1/36}{1/4}$

But I'm not sure about this, please help! I'm learning for an exam!!

Comment: Note that while in the total country population, one fourth of the people "like wine" but among those "who [wear] glasses" only one ninth of them like wine.  So the events of liking wine and wearing glasses are not independent.  You need to do some cases to work out (1.) the fraction of the people who like wine and wear glasses, and (2.) the conditional probability of wearing glasses given that a citizen "doesn't like wine".

Comment: Concentrate on what fraction of citizens wear glasses (versus the fraction who do not wear glasses).